# Is there a name for this equation? $\xi^4 v'' + \alpha\mathrm{e}^v = 0$, where $ v = v(\xi)$

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, boundary-value-problem

Consider the problem

> $$\xi^4 v'' + \alpha \, \mathrm{e}^v = 0, \quad v = v(\xi), \quad 1 < \xi < \infty, $$

with boundary conditions $v(1) = 0$ and $|v| < \infty$  for all $\xi$ and $\alpha > 0$ is a real constant. This is closely related to the so-called Bratu-Gelfand problem, but in a different geometry. I arrived at this equation after performing some change of variable on the original problem. Though this seems easier, it is most likely this problem has not a closed-form solution.

Does anyone spot a useful change of variables here? Moreover, does it have a name?

Any thoughts are greatly appreciated.

Comment: $v=v(\xi)\quad$?

Comment: Yes, I'll edit the question to make it more clear.

Comment: Why the weird variables? Why not just $x^4 y'' + ae^y = 0, y=y(x), 1 < x < \infty$?

Comment: @martycohen, this problem has a physical background, so I decided to keep the nomenclature that I was using along the derivation of the problem.

Comment: It is a second order differential equation. Is there another boundary condition ... do you want the solution to contain an arbitary constant ?

Comment: @DonaldSplutterwit, the boundedness condition should suffice to find an analytical solution for $v$. By geometry considerations, it is expected that $v' \to 0$ as $\xi \to \infty$. Yes, though the solution may not be unique for a given range of values of $\alpha$.

Answer (score 1):

$\xi^4v''+\alpha e^v=0$

$\dfrac{d^2v}{d\xi^2}=-\alpha\xi^{-4}e^v$

Approach $1$:

Follow the method in http://science.fire.ustc.edu.cn/download/download1/book%5Cmathematics%5CHandbook%20of%20Exact%20Solutions%20for%20Ordinary%20Differential%20EquationsSecond%20Edition%5Cc2972_fm.pdf#page=440:

$\therefore\dfrac{d^2\xi}{dv^2}=\alpha\xi^{-4}e^v\left(\dfrac{d\xi}{dv}\right)^3$

Let $\begin{cases}t=\dfrac{d\xi}{dv}\\u=\xi^{-3}\end{cases}$ ,

Then $\dfrac{d^2v}{dt^2}=\dfrac{tv^{-\frac{4}{3}}}{3}\left(\dfrac{dv}{dt}\right)^2$

Which reduces to a generalized Emden–Fowler equation.

Approach $2$:

Follow the method in http://eqworld.ipmnet.ru/en/solutions/ode/ode0314.pdf:

Let $\begin{cases}t=\xi^{-2}e^v\\u=\xi\dfrac{dv}{d\xi}\end{cases}$ ,

Then $t(u-2)\dfrac{du}{dt}=-\alpha t+u$

Which reduces to an Abel equation of the second kind.

Comment: Thx! I thought I could take if from here, but I realized this is far more complicated than I expected. I couldn't reduce this equation further using the references you provided. I guess this problem hasn't any closed-form solution at all and I should therefore give up!